# Setting up Yii2 project in localy system in Window XAMPP getting error

Tags: php, windows, yii, yii2, xampp

I'm setting up Yii2 project in locally system in window XAMPP and I'm getting an error:

> Declaration of common\components\Request::validateCsrfToken() should
>   be compatible with
>   yii\web\Request::validateCsrfToken($clientSuppliedToken = NULL)

[image: here is error screen capture]

But the code is working fine on Ubuntu server.

Here is my `validateCsrfToken()` method:

```
public function validateCsrfToken()
{
    if($this->enableCsrfValidation && in_array(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->parseRequest($this)[0], $this->noCsrfRoutes)){
        return true;
    }
    return parent::validateCsrfToken();
}
```

Comment: Is this `common\components\Request::validateCsrfToken()` your function?

Comment: Yes here is code in this function

`    public function validateCsrfToken()
    {
        if($this->enableCsrfValidation && in_array(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->parseRequest($this)[0], $this->noCsrfRoutes)){
            return true;
        }
        return parent::validateCsrfToken();
    }
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is because you are using `strict` PHP in Windows, but not in Linux. You own function `common\components\Request::validateCsrfToken()` should be compatible with `yii\web\Request::validateCsrfToken()`. This means, it needs to have the same signature.

What you can do at the moment is to change your own function to

```
public function validateCsrfToken($token = NULL) { 
    if ($this->enableCsrfValidation && in_array(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->parseRequest($this)[0], $this->noCsrfRoutes)) { 
        return true; 
    } 

    return parent::validateCsrfToken($token); 
}
```

You need to do this every time you are rewriting one of those functions (i.e. `beforeAction`, `afterAction`, `beforeSave` and many more...)

Comment: @Developer Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it helped you, so it might help other people in the future facing similar issues.